# Why C++ standard requires std::partition to meet different complexities for different types of iterator?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

The C++ standard requires `std::partition` to have different numbers of predicate applications between `ForwardIterator` and `BidirectionalIterator`. For the `ForwardIterator` version, the number of predicate applications shall be <= *N*, where *N* = `std::distance(first, last)`, but for the `BidirectionalIterator` version, the number of predicate applications shall be <= *N*/2. Obviously, both versions have time complexity *O*(*N*).

My question is, why does it bother to provide different requirements for different type of iterators? Such requirement forces a lot of compilers?

e.g: MSVC, implement the function `std::partition` in two ways to meet such requirement, which does not seem to be very elegant.

A further question: Are there any algorithm that relies on this coefficient, such that when *N*/2 becomes *N*, the asymptotic complexity will be different? For my understanding, if we consider the `Master's Theorem`, for the form in `T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)`, the coefficient in `f(n)` does not matter much.

C.f. An equivalent implementation of MSVC's partition:

```
template<class BidirIt, class UnaryPred>
BidirIt partition(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, UnaryPred pred, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag)
{
    while (true)
    {
        while ((first != last) && pred(*first))
        {
            ++first;
        }
        if (first == last)
        {
            break;
        }
        --last;
        while ((first != last) && !pred(*last))
        {
            --last;
        }
        if (first == last)
        {
            break;
        }
        std::iter_swap(first, last);
        ++first;
    }
    return first;
}
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPred> 
ForwardIt partition(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPred pred, std::forward_iterator_tag)
{
    first = std::find_if_not(first, last, pred);
    if (first == last)
    {
        return first;
    }

    for (ForwardIt src = std::next(first); src != last; ++src)
    {
        if (pred(*src))
        {
            std::iter_swap(first, src);
            ++src;
        }
    }
    return first;
}
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPred>
ForwardIt partition(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPred pred)
{
    return partition(first, last, pred, typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::iterator_category());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The predicate `pred` is executed exactly *N* times in both cases - every element must be tested once. The difference between `ForwardIterator` and `BidirectionalIterator` is in the amount of swaps.

`BidirectionalIterator` does at most *N/2* swaps, because it scans the range from the front and from the back at once, once it reaches value from the left that doesn't fulfill the predicate and value from right that does fulfill it, it swaps them. So in worst case it can do it's job in *N/2* swaps.

`ForwardIterator` doesn't have that advantage and in worst case may do a swap for every element.

The standard requires those two different limitations, because they are both the best one can get. So programmers can rely that every standard library implementation will behave that way.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. As pointed out, I made a mistake on the number of predicate applications.
Both versions are for *N* applications. It is the number of swaps that differs. Now I can understand the standard requires so since it is the optimal requirement. Thanks again for your kind answers. :)

Answer (score 3):

That's true, time complexity is still the same.

Important thing to note is that swaps are actually quite expensive. Especially for large objects. Most of the time they involve three move operations. In such scenarios we should reduce the amount of swaps to minimum. By using bidirectional iterators we get significant improvement in terms of efficiency, even though time complexity is the same.

Remember, that in the real environment it might be crucial for simple operations to be performed fast. Whenever there is a possibility to do so, it should be done this way. When working with complex algorithms (often for NP-complete problems variations) that take a lot of time to compute it might be crucial to perform operation in half less time. Would you prefer to have a lag of 0.2 seconds to 0.1 seconds? The time complexity is a bunch of nice theory but real world is not so beautiful and every fraction of the second is important.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Now I can understand that the standard hopes to optimize the number of swap since the swap operation may be expensive.

Thanks again for your kind answers. :)

Comment: "Especially for large objects. Most of the time they involve three copy operations."... I hope not! For a correctly implemented data structure it would involve three move operations or PIMPL pointer swaps. When applied correctly, swapping isn't expensive. Obviously still better to do half as many cheap operations.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus yeah, I meant move operations of course. Correcting my mistake. Thank you.